# Count occurrences within specific date criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences in a list of data where a task is completed `(column G - completed date)` prior to it's due date `(column F - due date)`, but also looking at only those records where the due date is between a user selected range `(cell F86 - from date, cell G86 - to date)`.
I've tried using `COUNTIFS` for the multiple criteria but that doesn't seem to handle ranges, and I've tried combining with `SUMPRODUCTS` with no luck. One example formula shown below:

```
=COUNTIFS(G7:G83,"<=" &F7:F83,G7:G83,"<> 0",F7:F83,">="&F86,F7:F83,"<="&G86)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT is what's required.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G7:G83<=F7:F83)*(G7:G83<>0)*(F7:F83>=F86)*(F7:F83<=G86))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you, appreciate the help.